# How to images store localy from xml using flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have one XML link which has collections of images (~1000 images).

When I flex applications start at the time load all images in locally. Then when I need that images then use it.

How I do this using flex 3?

Comment: Please correct english and explain a bit better.  I don't know what you're trying to accomplish.  You just want to load the images locally? then what?  The browser caches the images automatically, so really you only need to display them in the UI...

Answer (score 0):

1. Load the .xml form server or so.
2. Parse the .xml and create a Map where you store all the image URLs
3. Place an Image Component on your UI and set the "source" property to the value of the image URL
4. Flash Plugin will load the image from the URL and will show the image when done.
5. If you are facing a "SandboxVaiolationException" (or something like that) you need to tell your server to let the request go.

If you want to change the "source" Property of the Image at runtime, just set it after a click oder an other Event. (is no problem)